# How do I space fixed and variable-length TextViews in a two-column layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I require a two-column layout where the right column is a fixed string and the left column may be text of any length, and should wrap if it doesn't fit.

In other words, I want this:

```
 +-----------------------------------------------------------+------------+
 | This text may be any length and should wrap if it doesn't | Fixed Text |
 | fit in the first column.                                  |            |
 +-----------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

But instead I always get this:

```
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | This text may be any length and should wrap if it doesn't fit in the   |
 | first column.                                                          |
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried a RelativeLayout and a LinearLayout with various combinations of widths and weights but I usually get the second result.

Instead of posting all my failed attempts, can someone kindly just post what works? It shouldn't be this difficult. >8-(

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width=“match_parent”
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using a linearLayout with sepecific weight.

```
<LinearLayout
<!-- This will hold a row -->
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="horizontal"
...>
    <LinearLayout
    <!-- Variable TextView placeholder-->
    android:weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ...>
    <!-- TextView here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    <!-- Fixed TextView placeholder-->
    android:weight="2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ...>
    <!-- TextView here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a table layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Column 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_weight=".67"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:text="Column 2" 
        android:layout_weight=".33"/>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```